# How do we use groupby and rolling fuctions and maintain structure of the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to search through the following "patients" by their ID # ['PAT_MRN_ID'] to see whether they have either two consecutive positive results for either NG or CT in a 90 day period. If they do, I'd like a sum of the positive results per each ID # with the specific dates of those results.

My intention is to later remove patients that have >=2 positive results in a 90 day period from my data set. I am able to run the data through the groupby and then through rolling. However, doing so results in truncation of the dataframe to only 3 colums.

An example of the df is as follows:

| PAT_NAME | PAT_MRN_ID | AGE | GENDER | ETHNICITY | RACE | ORDER_INST | TEST_TYPE | RESULTS | ALL_RESULTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bee, Max | 1234 | 24 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | Black | 1/20/2023 | NG | negative | False |
| Jones, Jim | 12345 | 35 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | White | 1/01/2022 | NG | negative | False |
| Jones, Jim | 12345 | 35 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | White | 3/16/2022 | CT | positive | True |
| Jones, Jim | 12345 | 35 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | White | 3/17/2022 | CT | positive | True |
| Rell, Hell | 123456 | 30 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | Asian | 3/03/2022 | NG | positive | True |
| Rell, Hell | 123456 | 30 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | Asian | 3/03/2022 | CT | positive | True |
| Writer, JR | 1234567 | 88 | Female | Hispanic or Latinx | Asian | 1/03/2022 | CT | positive | True |
| Writer, JR | 1234567 | 88 | Female | Hispanic or Latinx | Asian | 9/03/2022 | CT | positive | True |
| Ron, Cam | 12345678 | 55 | Male | Black | Black | 9/03/2022 | CT | positive | True |
| Ron, Cam | 12345678 | 55 | Male | Black | Black | 9/03/2022 | CT | positive | True |

Tried the following:

```
df['SUM'] = df.groupby(["PAT_MRN_ID","TEST_TYPE"],as_index=False)['ORDER_INST', 'TEST_TYPE', 'ALL_RESULTS'].rolling('90d', min_periods=2, on='ORDER_INST')['ALL_RESULTS'].sum()
```

> ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Expected:

| PAT_NAME | PAT_MRN_ID | AGE | GENDER | ETHNICITY | RACE | ORDER_INST | TEST_TYPE | RESULTS | ALL_RESULTS | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bee, Max | 1234 | 24 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | Black | 1/20/2023 | NG | negative | False | NaN |
| Jones, Jim | 12345 | 35 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | White | 1/01/2022 | NG | negative | False | NaN |
| Jones, Jim | 12345 | 35 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | White | 3/16/2022 | CT | positive | True | NaN |
| Jones, Jim | 12345 | 35 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | White | 3/17/2022 | CT | positive | True | 2 |
| Rell, Hell | 123456 | 30 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | Asian | 3/03/2022 | NG | positive | True | NaN |
| Rell, Hell | 123456 | 30 | Male | Hispanic or Latinx | Asian | 3/03/2022 | CT | positive | True | NaN |
| Writer, JR | 1234567 | 88 | Female | Hispanic or Latinx | Asian | 1/03/2022 | CT | positive | True | NaN |
| Writer, JR | 1234567 | 88 | Female | Hispanic or Latinx | Asian | 9/03/2022 | CT | positive | True | NaN |
| Ron, Cam | 12345678 | 55 | Male | Black | Black | 9/03/2022 | CT | positive | True |  |
| Ron, Cam | 12345678 | 55 | Male | Black | Black | 9/03/2022 | CT | positive | True | 2 |

If I attempt the following:

```
df.groupby(["PAT_MRN_ID","TEST_TYPE"],as_index=False)['ORDER_INST', 'TEST_TYPE', 'ALL_RESULTS'].rolling('90d', min_periods=2, on='ORDER_INST')['ALL_RESULTS'].sum()
```

I get this:

| PAT_MRN_ID | ORDER_INST | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1/20/2023 | NaN |
| 12345 | 1/01/2022 | Nan |
| 12345 | 3/16/2022 | NaN |
| 12345 | 3/17/2022 | 2 |
| 123456 | 3/03/2022 | NaN |
| 123456 | 3/03/2022 | NaN |
| 1234567 | 9/03/2022 | NaN |
| 1234567 | 9/03/2022 | NaN |
| 12345678 | 9/03/2022 | NaN |
| 12345678 | 9/03/2022 | 2 |

Furthermore, I have tried passing this through transform(lambda x: x.rolling()) and get:

> ValueError: invalid on specified as ORDER_INST, must be a column (of DataFrame), an Index or None
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> ValueError: transform must return a scalar value for each group

I also attempted turing ['ALL_RESULTS'] from 'True'/'False' into '1'/'0' respectively to give transform a "scalar;" however, that also failed to work.

In an ideal world I want to keep the original dataframe format and add a row for the rolling sum OR simply just remove the instance of duplicate positive test results in a 90 day period from the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) by MultiIndex, also was removed `TEST_TYPE` column and `as_index=False` parameter:

```
df['ORDER_INST'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ORDER_INST'])

df = (df.join(df.groupby(["PAT_MRN_ID","TEST_TYPE"])[['ORDER_INST', 'ALL_RESULTS']]
                .rolling('90d', min_periods=2, on='ORDER_INST')['ALL_RESULTS']
                .sum().rename('SUM'), on=['PAT_MRN_ID','TEST_TYPE','ORDER_INST']))
print (df)
      PAT_NAME  PAT_MRN_ID  AGE   GENDER            ETHNICITY    RACE  \
0    Bee, Max         1234   24    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   Black    
1  Jones, Jim        12345   35    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   White    
2  Jones, Jim        12345   35    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   White    
3  Jones, Jim        12345   35    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   White    
4  Rell, Hell       123456   30    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   Asian    
5  Rell, Hell       123456   30    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   Asian    
6  Writer, JR      1234567   88  Female   Hispanic or Latinx   Asian    
7  Writer, JR      1234567   88  Female   Hispanic or Latinx   Asian    

  ORDER_INST TEST_TYPE    RESULTS  ALL_RESULTS  SUM  
0 2023-01-20       NG   negative         False  NaN  
1 2022-01-01       NG   negative         False  NaN  
2 2022-03-16       CT   positive          True  NaN  
3 2022-03-17       CT   positive          True  2.0  
4 2022-03-03       NG   positive          True  NaN  
5 2022-03-03       CT   positive          True  NaN  
6 2022-01-03       CT   positive          True  NaN  
7 2022-09-03       CT   positive          True  NaN
```

EDIT: I add [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter of duplicated values:

```
df['ORDER_INST'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ORDER_INST'])

df1 = (df.groupby(["PAT_MRN_ID","TEST_TYPE"])[['ORDER_INST', 'ALL_RESULTS']]
         .rolling('90d', min_periods=2, on='ORDER_INST')['ALL_RESULTS']
         .sum()
         .to_frame('SUM')
         .assign(g = lambda x:x.groupby(['PAT_MRN_ID','TEST_TYPE','ORDER_INST']).cumcount())
         .set_index('g', append=True))


df['g'] = df.groupby(['PAT_MRN_ID','TEST_TYPE','ORDER_INST']).cumcount()
df = df.join(df1, on=['PAT_MRN_ID','TEST_TYPE','ORDER_INST','g']).drop('g', axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
      PAT_NAME  PAT_MRN_ID  AGE   GENDER            ETHNICITY    RACE  \
0    Bee, Max         1234   24    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   Black    
1  Jones, Jim        12345   35    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   White    
2  Jones, Jim        12345   35    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   White    
3  Jones, Jim        12345   35    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   White    
4  Rell, Hell       123456   30    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   Asian    
5  Rell, Hell       123456   30    Male   Hispanic or Latinx   Asian    
6  Writer, JR      1234567   88  Female   Hispanic or Latinx   Asian    
7  Writer, JR      1234567   88  Female   Hispanic or Latinx   Asian    
8    Ron, Cam     12345678   55    Male                Black   Black    
9    Ron, Cam     12345678   55    Male                Black   Black    

  ORDER_INST TEST_TYPE    RESULTS  ALL_RESULTS  SUM  
0 2023-01-20       NG   negative         False  NaN  
1 2022-01-01       NG   negative         False  NaN  
2 2022-03-16       CT   positive          True  NaN  
3 2022-03-17       CT   positive          True  2.0  
4 2022-03-03       NG   positive          True  NaN  
5 2022-03-03       CT   positive          True  NaN  
6 2022-01-03       CT   positive          True  NaN  
7 2022-09-03       CT   positive          True  NaN  
8 2022-09-03       CT   positive          True  NaN  
9 2022-09-03       CT   positive          True  2.0
```

Comment: Jezrael, thank you. For some reason when I run it on a slightly larger test dataframe where the last 2 patients have positive test reults on the same date, the ouput doubles the information. So instead of stopping at index 7, for example, it duplicates everything at 7 onto index 8.

There will be instances in the dataset where people are tested twice on the same day and could potentially have a positive result with the same date.

Comment: @Harlemworld - Is possible change data in question for verify your problem? Because now not idea whats happens.

Comment: I have added 2 rows at the bottom with patient named "Ron, Cam" his tests are both positive on same day. your code gave:

|1234567| 9/03/2022|NaN|
|1234567| 9/03/2022 |NaN|
|12345678| 9/03/2022|NaN|
|12345678| 9/03/2022 |2|
|12345678| 9/03/2022|NaN|
|12345678| 9/03/2022 |2|